# Colors looks different on Mac and Windows PC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I am using 2 computers - Mac Mini and Windows PC - both of these are connected to one monitor.
Today I did a UI case study on Mac Mini and saved it there. Everything looked normal, but then I sent it to my windows PC and all the colors seem to changed significantly.
Do you know where the issue might be?
I would understand that there might be color difference in different monitors, but since i am using just 1 monitor for both, I have no idea where could be the problem.

Comment: You could calibrate both systems using a calibration device.  This doesn't just  apply to mac versus PC, but every brand of computer and monitor in existence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies at the other end of the cable: different hardware & software (PC vs Mac) sending different rendering to the same monitor. Alot of settings in both your PC and Mac can affect this, and there's no magic button to 'sync' settings affecting color rendering.

If I had this problem, I would not worry much. My client will probably see a third set of colors.

Comment: The thing is, without accurate calibration using a hardware colorimeter, you'll never know which is right or wrong… or if either of them are in fact right.